# Joomla 4 - Cassiopeia index.php override

Tags: joomla-4.x, template-override, cassiopeia

I have created a child template from the main cassiopeia template and I can see it there.

I then created an index.php in the root of the child template folder. Making changes to this file doesn't reflect on the site however? Basically it is not picking up the override child template index.php.

Are there further steps I need to take. The XML has the following:

```
  <inheritable>0</inheritable>
  <parent>cassiopeia</parent>
```

Comment: What did  you expect this index.php file to do?  Is the child template set as the default?

Comment: @HuwEvans, I am literally just trying to load the carousel component for the index page (and maybe elsewhere on the site). So just a one line change. 

How do you check the child template is set as the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out it wasn't reflecting my changes because I didnt assign the child template to the main menu in template styles.